# Execute a function if hovered on image, Javascript

Tags: javascript

Basically, what I'd like is that a function is called whenever someone hovers on an img tag, and the changes the function made are removed when the user stops hovering.

What in trying to do is that add some html after an image when it is hovered on, and if there is no hover on any image, It clears the added html.

So basically, something like, if any image on The page is hovered on, run function (which can manipulate the image which is hovered, using outerhtml most probably) and if the user isn't hovering on any image, all images outer html should be blank.

I'd prefer a solution that is vanilla Javascript instead of jq.

I hope I'm making sense here.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot do what you want with just CSS and `img:hover`?

Comment: As I said, I need to add html, so it work using css. If it would, it would require a load of unnecessary html, and it couldn't beer automated.

Comment: @Namanyayg I think Jon's point is that you might be able to use CSS but we can't tell from your question. For example you can have the HTML you're talking about adding/removing already be on the page, but hidden, then display/hide it using CSS - this is still likely to perform better than adding/removing HTML. Whether or not you can do this depends on what you're actually doing though, for example if it's different HTML every time you obviously can't do that.

Comment: Social media buttons are to be loaded. Afaik, to change things through CSS, it should be nested, and to nest it, ill need to manually change every image. I also want the html to be just outside the image, not somewhere else, so thought that outerhtml would be the best. What would you say is the css solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
function DoWork() {};
function RevertWork() {};

var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
    imgs[i].onmouseover = DoWork;
    imgs[i].onmouseout = RevertWork;
}
```

Comment: Do what it sites is, runs the function using each image on the webpage, right? So, if there are 10 images, it world run 20 function s, if I'm not wrong.. Wouldn't it increase load, or will it be fine?

Comment: @Namanyayg it would run only once for each mouseover and mouseout event. So the number of event handlers does not decrease performance in terms of loading time.